# Prophet installation is failing in with pip on mac m1, python3.11

Tags: python-3.x, macos, machine-learning, time-series, facebook-prophet

Prophet and kats installation is failing in the apple mac m1 chip environment and same issue is happening in windows also. Below are the environment details and pip packages installed as a dependency. Please help to resolve the issue.

```
Python version: 3.11.4
Chip: Mac M1
Pip packages:
Package         Version
--------------- -------
cmdstanpy       1.1.0
numpy           1.25.2
pandas          2.0.3
pip             23.2.1
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz            2023.3
setuptools      68.0.0
six             1.16.0
tqdm            4.65.1
tzdata          2023.3
```

Stack Trace

```
                        ^
      In file included from src/cmdstan/stansummary.cpp:1:
      In file included from src/cmdstan/stansummary_helper.hpp:4:
      In file included from stan/src/stan/mcmc/chains.hpp:4:
      In file included from stan/src/stan/io/stan_csv_reader.hpp:4:
      In file included from stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.78.0/boost/algorithm/string.hpp:23:
      In file included from stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.78.0/boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp:16:
      In file included from stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.78.0/boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp:27:
      In file included from stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.78.0/boost/algorithm/string/find_iterator.hpp:24:
      In file included from stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.78.0/boost/algorithm/string/detail/find_iterator.hpp:18:
      In file included from stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.78.0/boost/function.hpp:30:
      In file included from stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.78.0/boost/function/detail/prologue.hpp:17:
      In file included from stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.78.0/boost/function/function_base.hpp:23:
      stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.78.0/boost/type_traits/has_trivial_destructor.hpp:30:86: warning: builtin __has_trivial_destructor is deprecated; use __is_trivially_destructible instead [-Wdeprecated-builtins]
      template <typename T> struct has_trivial_destructor : public integral_constant<bool, BOOST_HAS_TRIVIAL_DESTRUCTOR(T)>{};
                                                                                           ^
      stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.78.0/boost/type_traits/intrinsics.hpp:196:47: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_HAS_TRIVIAL_DESTRUCTOR'
      #     define BOOST_HAS_TRIVIAL_DESTRUCTOR(T) (__has_trivial_destructor(T)  && is_destructible<T>::value)
                                                    ^
      stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.78.0/boost/function/function_template.hpp:946:20: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::has_trivial_destructor<boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>>>' requested here
                  boost::has_trivial_destructor<Functor>::value &&
                         ^
      stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.78.0/boost/function/function_template.hpp:720:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::function2<boost::iterator_range<std::__wrap_iter<char *>>, std::__wrap_iter<char *>, std::__wrap_iter<char *>>::assign_to<boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>>>' requested here
            this->assign_to(f);
                  ^
      stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.78.0/boost/algorithm/string/detail/find_iterator.hpp:51:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::function2<boost::iterator_range<std::__wrap_iter<char *>>, std::__wrap_iter<char *>, std::__wrap_iter<char *>>::function2<boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>>>' requested here
                          m_Finder(Finder) {}
                          ^
      stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.78.0/boost/algorithm/string/find_iterator.hpp:261:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::algorithm::detail::find_iterator_base<std::__wrap_iter<char *>>::find_iterator_base<boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>>>' requested here
                      detail::find_iterator_base<IteratorT>(Finder,0),
                      ^
      stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.78.0/boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp:178:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::algorithm::split_iterator<std::__wrap_iter<char *>>::split_iterator<boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>>>' requested here
                          find_iterator_type( ::boost::begin(lit_input), InputEnd, Finder ),
                          ^
      stan/lib/stan_math/lib/boost_1.78.0/boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp:158:40: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::algorithm::iter_split<std::vector<std::string>, std::string &, boost::algorithm::detail::token_finderF<boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>>>' requested here
                  return ::boost::algorithm::iter_split(
                                             ^
      src/cmdstan/stansummary.cpp:82:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::algorithm::split<std::vector<std::string>, std::string &, boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>>' requested here
        boost::algorithm::split(percentiles, percentiles_spec, boost::is_any_of(", "),
                          ^
      43 warnings generated.
      43 warnings generated.
      45 warnings generated.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/Licious/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/Licious/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Users/Licious/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/49/ptrwr_w135x7rbt0__3kv5080000gp/T/pip-build-env-rqmxbvgv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 416, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/49/ptrwr_w135x7rbt0__3kv5080000gp/T/pip-build-env-rqmxbvgv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 401, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/49/ptrwr_w135x7rbt0__3kv5080000gp/T/pip-build-env-rqmxbvgv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 200, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/49/ptrwr_w135x7rbt0__3kv5080000gp/T/pip-build-env-rqmxbvgv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/49/ptrwr_w135x7rbt0__3kv5080000gp/T/pip-build-env-rqmxbvgv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/49/ptrwr_w135x7rbt0__3kv5080000gp/T/pip-build-env-rqmxbvgv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/private/var/folders/49/ptrwr_w135x7rbt0__3kv5080000gp/T/pip-build-env-rqmxbvgv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/private/var/folders/49/ptrwr_w135x7rbt0__3kv5080000gp/T/pip-build-env-rqmxbvgv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/49/ptrwr_w135x7rbt0__3kv5080000gp/T/pip-build-env-rqmxbvgv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/49/ptrwr_w135x7rbt0__3kv5080000gp/T/pip-build-env-rqmxbvgv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 349, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "/private/var/folders/49/ptrwr_w135x7rbt0__3kv5080000gp/T/pip-build-env-rqmxbvgv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/49/ptrwr_w135x7rbt0__3kv5080000gp/T/pip-build-env-rqmxbvgv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/49/ptrwr_w135x7rbt0__3kv5080000gp/T/pip-build-env-rqmxbvgv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/49/ptrwr_w135x7rbt0__3kv5080000gp/T/pip-build-env-rqmxbvgv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/private/var/folders/49/ptrwr_w135x7rbt0__3kv5080000gp/T/pip-build-env-rqmxbvgv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/49/ptrwr_w135x7rbt0__3kv5080000gp/T/pip-build-env-rqmxbvgv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/49/ptrwr_w135x7rbt0__3kv5080000gp/T/pip-build-env-rqmxbvgv/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "<string>", line 161, in run
        File "<string>", line 148, in build_models
        File "<string>", line 122, in build_cmdstan_model
        File "<string>", line 99, in install_cmdstan_deps
      RuntimeError: CmdStan failed to install in repackaged directory
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for prophet
Failed to build prophet
ERROR: Could not build wheels for prophet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have tried multiple methods, even tried to create new python environment still it failing. Stacktrace is given above